# How to automatically generate typescript interfaces for redux connected components

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, redux, redux-thunk

Is there a way to automatically extend the interface of a connected component using the types of `mapStateToProps` and `mapDispatchToProps`? For example, the following code:

```
interface ComponentProps {
  state?: State;
  action?: (id: string) => void;
}

const mapStateToProps = (state: any) => ({
  state: state,
});

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch: any) => ({
  action: (id: string) => dispatch(Action),
});

const Component = (props: ComponentProps) => <div>...</div>;

export const ConnectedComponent = connect(
  mapStateToProps,
  mapDispatchToProps,
)(Component);
```

requires me to add the `state` and `action` as optional props to my `ComponentProps` in order to make use of them in my component since the props will be assigned by the `connect` HOC.

When using something like materialUI and its `withStyles` HOC, we can use `WithStyles<typeof styles>` to automatically add `classes` prop (with exact keys depending on `styles`) to our interface like

```
ComponentProps extends WithStyles<typeof styles> {
  actualProps: any;
}

const ConnectedComponent = withStyles(styles)(Component);
```

Would it be possible to do the same for `connect`?

Answer (score 2):

Here is how it's done in the [react-redux-typescript-guide](https://github.com/piotrwitek/react-redux-typescript-guide#redux-connected-components):

```
import Types from 'MyTypes';
import { bindActionCreators, Dispatch } from 'redux';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import * as React from 'react';

import { countersActions } from '../features/counters';

// Thunk Action
const incrementWithDelay = () => async (dispatch: Dispatch): Promise<void> => {
  setTimeout(() => dispatch(countersActions.increment()), 1000);
};

const mapStateToProps = (state: Types.RootState) => ({
  count: state.counters.reduxCounter,
});

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch: Dispatch<Types.RootAction>) =>
  bindActionCreators(
    {
      onIncrement: incrementWithDelay,
    },
    dispatch
  );

type Props = ReturnType<typeof mapStateToProps> &
  ReturnType<typeof mapDispatchToProps> & {
    label: string;
  };

export const FCCounter: React.FC<Props> = props => {
  const { label, count, onIncrement } = props;

  const handleIncrement = () => {
    // Thunk action is correctly typed as promise
    onIncrement().then(() => {
      // ...
    });
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <span>
        {label}: {count}
      </span>
      <button type="button" onClick={handleIncrement}>
        {`Increment`}
      </button>
    </div>
  );
};

export const FCCounterConnectedBindActionCreators = connect(
  mapStateToProps,
  mapDispatchToProps
)(FCCounter);
```

You should use `ReturnType` helper:

```
type Props = ReturnType<typeof mapStateToProps> & ReturnType<typeof mapDispatchToProps> {
  label: string;
};
```